# Algebraic expression for $\frac{x^z}{z} + \frac{x^{\bar{z}}}{\bar{z}}$ using only real variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, exponential-function, exponentiation

**UPDATED:**

*(I originally asked for a proof that the expression was real; I meant to ask for the real algebraic expression that the sum equates to - i.e., an expression in terms of $x$, $\sigma$ and $t$ but not $i$.)*

Let $z = \sigma + i t$ be a complex number and let $\bar{z} = \sigma - i t$ be its conjugate. Let $x$ be a positive real number. I want to find the real expression corresponding to

$$\frac{x^z}{z} + \frac{x^{\bar{z}}}{\bar{z}}$$

(I am generalising from an expression in von Mangoldt's explicit formula for the Chebyshev $\psi$ function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#The_exact_formula).)

I realise that since $\frac{x^{\bar{z}}}{\bar{z}}$ is the conjugate of $\frac{x^z}{z}$, their sum must be real - but what form does it take?

This should involve a fairly simple piece of algebra, but I can't get there. I begin as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{x^z}{z} + \frac{x^{\bar{z}}}{\bar{z}} &= \frac{x^{\sigma +i t}}{\sigma +i t}+\frac{x^{\sigma -i t}}{\sigma -i t}
\\ &= \frac{e^{(\sigma +i t) \log (x)}}{\sigma +i t}+\frac{e^{(\sigma -i t) \log (x)}}{\sigma -i t}
\\ &= \frac{(\sigma +i t) e^{(\sigma -i t) \log (x)}+(\sigma -i t) e^{(\sigma +i t) \log (x)}}{\sigma ^2+t^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

But I don't know how to proceed. I'd like to apply Euler's identity, but as far as I'm aware, the identity $e^{a+ib} = e^a e^{ib}$ does not apply because the original exponent is complex, so I cannot split out the complex component of $e^{(\sigma \pm i t) \log (x)}$. And even if it is valid to write $e^{a+ib} = e^a e^{ib}$, I still end up with a factor of $-2 i \sin (t \log (x))$ in the numerator.

Could someone show me how to arrive at the purely real expression that $\frac{x^z}{z} + \frac{x^{\bar{z}}}{\bar{z}}$ resolves to?

Comment: $e^{z+w} = e^z e^w$ for *all* $z, w$.

Comment: Thank you @Unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is almost done.
$$
2\,{\frac {{{\rm e}^{\sigma\,\ln  x }} \big( \sigma\cos
 \left( t\ln  x   \right)+t \sin \left( t\ln 
 x   \right) \big) }{{\sigma}^{2}+{t}^{2}}}
$$

Comment: Hi @ GEdgar. Could you perhaps expand on this? I can't see where $t sin(t \ln x)$ comes from. I suspect you are using trig identities that I have forgotten or am unaware of, because for that portion of the calculation I end up with $e^{-i t \log (x)}-e^{i t \log (x)}=\cos (t \log (x))-i \sin (t \log (x))-\cos (t \log (x))-i \sin (t \log (x))=-2 i \sin (t \log (x))$.

Answer (score 1):

The complex conjugate of the first term is exactly the second term. Hence their sum  is real.

$x^{z}=e^{z \ln x}$ and the conjugate of $e^{c}$ is $e^{\overline c}$ as seen using power series.

Comment: Hi @Kavi. My apologies: I do realise that the sum of a complex number and its conjugate is always real. I was hoping for the real expression the sum equates to. I'll amend my OP.